# understanding placement in this query

Tags: sql

I have made multiple attempts to "group" the results of this query by using
`Group By`, `Distinct`, etc.

I understand what I want to achieve, combining multiple results, but I am still very new to SQL. I have been experimenting with several clauses and nothing seems to work. I have been working on this for most of the day. I am finally at my wits end.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT
  PAYER_PLAN_NAME,PAYER_NAME,ACTUAL_BEGIN_DATETIME,
  ACTUAL_END_DATETIME,CLIENT_NAME,BEGIN_DATE,END_DATE,
  POLICY_NUMBER,ID_NUMBER 
FROM RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN P
JOIN RPT_SCHEDULED_ACTIVITIES A ON P.CLIENT_ID = A.CLIENT_ID
WHERE trunc(ACTUAL_BEGIN_DATETIME) >= ${p_begin_time} 
  AND trunc(ACTUAL_END_DATETIME) <= ${p_end_time}
  AND trunc(BEGIN_DATE) <= ${END_DATE}
  AND trunc(END_DATE)> ${BEGIN_DATE} 
   OR trunc(END_DATE) IS NULL
```

Comment: I should add that I am trying to group Client_name so multiple results are combined into one entry.

Comment: OK, when you group by `client_name`, what do you want to do with the other columns? Getting the `sum()`, the `max()`, the `min()`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. The other columns are insurance types and numbers. I don't know what to do with the other columns because they are insurance types and numbers. I wouldn't want the sum or max or anything. Just to group clients with their respective insurance company, policy number, ect. Sorry, I have been learning SQL for about 3 weeks now. Noobville

Comment: The worst part is being so new and learning. The way I'm understanding, it's possible to group just one column? If the others were grouped as well, they would need to be dependent on the client name, I think?

Comment: In SQL the concept of "grouping" means that you are producing a **single** row from multiple ones. If you group by `client_name`, then you will produce a single row per each client name. Now, on each resulting row you also want the `BEGIN_DATE`, but... there can be multiple **different** values for it (since you are grouping); so, the question is... which one do you pick? The smallest one, the biggest one, the average... you need to choose, since there's place for only one.

Comment: The most accurate way to think about `GROUP BY` is that you're putting rows into groups where they share the same values in the `GROUP BY` columns. From there, you can `SELECT` any of the columns used in the `GROUP BY`, or you can use aggregate functions like `MIN()`, `MAX()` etc on the fields that were not included in the group. You say you want to group by `Client_name`. Why? What benefit does putting the records into groups where they share a `Client_name` provide you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow CodingAintEasy ! It would help if you could edit your question and add  sample data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assist. I just finished a class in C# at college and was thrown into SQL at my job. I may have been on the wrong track with GROUP BY. I need to get one single dedicated book, instead of using the web to learn. Lot's of conflicting info. Sorry for being a pain with stupid questions. I found several explanations of GROUP BY and I even asked my Boss about "Same values need to be in each.  SO What am I trying to do here. The client_names field populates with several duplicate entries once the query runs. The report is to show people who have active insurance.

Comment: When I run the query, the same name shows up multiple times. Then the report runs 800 pages. I'm just trying to get the results for each individual, once. When I order by name, I see 20-30 of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example but it might help you understand how the GROUP BY feature works:

```
SELECT CLIENT_NAME
   , min(BEGIN_DATE) AS Effective_start
   , max(END_DATE) AS Effective_end
   , first(POLICY_NUMBER) AS Policy_number    FROM RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN P
JOIN RPT_SCHEDULED_ACTIVITIES A ON P.CLIENT_ID = A.CLIENT_ID
WHERE trunc(ACTUAL_BEGIN_DATETIME) >= ${p_begin_time} 
  AND trunc(ACTUAL_END_DATETIME) <= ${p_end_time}
  AND trunc(BEGIN_DATE) <= ${END_DATE}
  AND trunc(END_DATE)> ${BEGIN_DATE} 
   OR ISNULL(trunc(END_DATE), GETDATE())  -- sets end date to today id null
GROUP BY CLIENT_NAME
```

This should give you a table of Client_names, Effective_start (Earliest begin_date), Effective_end (oldest END_DATE, note comment for handling nulls you may want something different), and the first "policy_NUMBER" encountered by sql for each client_name.

I'm guess at your true objective but hopefully this will get you going again.

Comment: Thank you for the help. For whatever reason, I am not able to see the above code run. I get an error. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: I will also add, which makes things more confusing, that we are inputting the code into Pentaho report designer, which is Java based?!?! I am totally lost. SQL code works though, it's all I've ever used. I should have stayed with IT Specialist!! Now I'm a coding super noob.